# How to speed of my R code when I use igraph?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, matrix, graph-theory, igraph

When I am running the following code it takes like forever to be run. Any idea how to speed up the code? Like changing the layout of matrix or hashing or ... ??

I am aiming to create an edge-node triangle adjancey matrix at the very end and use it for co-clustering.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100, .6)
#print(g)
plot(g)
ij <- get.edgelist(g)
print(ij)
library(Matrix)
m <- sparseMatrix(
  i = rep(seq(nrow(ij)), each=2),
  j = as.vector(t(ij)),
  x = 1
)
print(m)
# Maximal cliques of size at least 3
cl <- maximal.cliques(g)
print(cl)
cl <- cl[ sapply(cl, length) > 2 ]
print(cl)
# Function to test if an edge is part of a triangle
triangle <- function(e) {
  any( sapply( cl, function(u) all( e %in% u ) ) )
}
print(triangle)
# Only keep those edges
kl <- ij[ apply(ij, 1, triangle), ]
print(kl)
# Same code as before
m <- sparseMatrix(
  i = rep(seq(nrow(kl)), each=2),
  j = as.vector(t(kl)),
  x = 1
)
print(m)
```

This is literally where the code is stuck:
[image]

Comment: I notice you have asked several good questions both here & on SO, @MonaJalal. However, some here (like this) belong on SO, & some on SO belong here. If what you need explained is a statistical (data visualization, etc) idea, the question should be asked here; if what you need explained is how to get R to do something, or why R did do something (eg, crash, as in this case), the Q belongs on SO. Since you are new to CV, please take our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about) to learn a little more about how CV works.

Comment: Thanks gung. Can you send this to SO? I wasn't sure where this should be posted. Thanks.

Comment: It will be migrated soon.

Comment: This is kind of misleading, because the screenshot is only showing the output, but not the actual code that is run. Your code gets stuck at `apply(ij, 1, triangle)`. I am sure that it is possible to speed this up, but it would be actually easier to write code from scratch to find all edges that are part of at least one triangle.